# Recuperar Select de Trigger qualquer

Tags: c#, sql, trigger

Como posso recuperar um `select` de uma `trigger`?

Exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE PESSOA2
(
    ID INTEGER IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    NOME VARCHAR(250)
)
 CREATE TRIGGER SELECIONAR_NOME2 ON DBO.PESSOA2
AFTER UPDATE AS 

BEGIN 
    SELECT * FROM PESSOA2

END


 INSERT INTO PESSOA2 (NOME) VALUES ('fulano1')
 INSERT INTO PESSOA2 (NOME) VALUES ('fulano2')
 INSERT INTO PESSOA2 (NOME) VALUES ('fulano3')
 INSERT INTO PESSOA2 (NOME) VALUES ('fulano4')
 INSERT INTO PESSOA2 (NOME) VALUES ('fulano5')

UPDATE PESSOA2 SET NOME = 'fulano0' WHERE NOME = 'fulano1'
```

Resultado após dar UPDATE: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] 
Nesse exemplo, quando eu der um `update` ele dá um `select` na tabela `pessoa`, o que quero saber é como consigo recuperar o `select` via aplicação c#?

Usando `try`{}`catch`{} consigo obter um retorno do erro, mas como recupero a tabela do select?

EX para obter retorno:

```
try
{
    identity = dbCommand.ExecuteXmlReader().toInt32(); //Não conseguiu exercutar? Gera uma Excepition gera um log para análise 
}                                                   // e procura por outra Exception.
catch (Exception e)
{
    if(e.Message == "Comando inválido enviado a ExecuteXmlReader. O comando deve retornar um resultado Xml.")
    {
        return;
    }
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Exceção banco de dados");

}
```

Comment: recuperar o select? o que vc quer dizer com isso?

Comment: HudsonPH tipo, quando dou um update na tabela pessoa2 a trigger é acionada, e então faz um select da tabela, como consigo recuperar esse select via aplicação c#?

Comment: mas qual a necessidade disso? nao seria mehor implementar no seu service o select retornando os novos valores? pq trigger + c# 'e para realtime app

Comment: Quero atualizar um `DataGridView`, tenho campos com vários usuários e Status(on-line ou off-line)
Quando um ficar on ou off eu atualizo o `DataGridView` Atualmente eu fiz com `Timer`, mas fica ruim, ficar atualizando atoa a cada certo tempo... :D 
Sabe uma maneira melhor? Me ajuda Por favor... :D

Comment: use esse nuget https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency

Comment: Vou conferir... um momento

Comment: Continuo sem entender? Primeiro que `Trigger` significa gatilho, substantivo masculino, ou seja *o* trigger é apenas um gatilho disparado após um evento DML. Segundo não se usa triggers dessa forma eles são mecanismos de propagação de alterações,para campos, outras tabelas ou outros bancos de dados, ativados após e apenas a alteração a qual foram associados. Terceiro a única forma de se recuperar o cursor para aquele select criar um cursor para aquele select com `DECLARE CURSOR` e posteriormente abri-lo com `OPEN` e se deslocar por esse cursor com `FETCH`. Continua...

Comment: O problema dessa operação não é a dificuldade e tempo que leva para implementá-la e sim o impacto que causa na memória e desempenho do servidor do banco de dados pois para cada cursor de um `SELECT *` é criado um `MIRROR` da tabela em questão dentro do servidor para cada cursor em atividade. 
Dito isso, pergunto. Não seria mais fácil após seu comando UPDATE fazer um SELECT dentro do C#?

Comment: Dei uma olhada na `Solution` que você mandou HudsonPH e não consegui compreender ela, está muito confusa e complexa.

Comment: Olá Augusto, obrigado pela resposta, então a aplicação que estou criando vai ser executada diversas vezes, imagine o cenário:

10 máquina executando ela, preciso saber quais dessas máquinas estão logadas na aplicação.
Eu fiz que, quando logar da um update na tabela pessoa e mude seu STS para = online.

Quando uma pessoa logar preciso atualizar um menu de viasualização que sera executado em outra máquina, como vou atualiza-lo?

Comment: Eu fiz com `Timer`, a cada 15 segundos faz select na tabela e atualiza o `DataGridView`.
Só que com isso leva tempo para atualizar e vai ficar atualizando mesmo se geral estiver Off-line. 

Pensei em fazer com trigger, quando algum client dar update na tabela e mudar seus STS, então eu identifico essa alteração e dou sselect na tabela, garantindo que somente quando alguém ficar on-line ou off-line novamente eu atualize o `DataGridView`

Comment: Vou repetir a resposta do @HudsonPH, use o componente [SqlTableDependency](https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency). Apenas o instale o pacote via nugget e use em sua aplicação.

Comment: Outra se você só que saber quem está online e offline não é mais fácil usar o [sp-who](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-who-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Então, seria interessante, saberia status  quando se conectar com o servidor, mas eu não sou desenvolvedor, estou apenas realizando um pequeno projeto, achei que seria mais fácil a solução para meu problema

Comment: Não consegui instalar o nugget.exe parece que tem que configurar uma variável de ambiente para conseguir executa-lo e dps instala-lo, não consigo instalar o pacote através do Visual Studio?

Comment: coloquei uma resposta e exemplo funcional, so precisa trocar o model e a connection para testar

Comment: ??? nugget.exe??? Menu Tools->Nuggets Package Manager->Manage Nugget Package for Solution...

Comment: Tem instador, mas o visual tem essa mão na roda kkkk vou instalar aqui

Comment: Acho que pra instalar precisa de uma outro versão do .Net uso a 4 para a aplicação

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Vocee pode usar o SqlTAbleDependency:

```
using System;
using TableDependency.SqlClient;
using TableDependency.SqlClient.Base.EventArgs;

namespace RealTimeUpdate
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }


    class Program
    {
        private static string connection = "data source=.; initial catalog=MyDB; integrated security=True";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlTableDependency<Customer> dep;
            using (dep = new SqlTableDependency<Customer>(connection, "Customers"));
            {                
                dep.OnChanged += Changed;
                dep.Start();

                Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit");
                Console.ReadKey();

                dep.Stop();
            }
        }

        public static void Changed(object sender, RecordChangedEventArgs<Customer> e)
        {
            var changedEntity = e.Entity;

            Console.WriteLine("DML operation: " + e.ChangeType);
            Console.WriteLine("ID: " + changedEntity.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + changedEntity.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Surame: " + changedEntity.Surname);
        }

    }
}
```

essa linha se refere ao nome de sua tabela `new SqlTableDependency<Customer>(connection, "Customers")` que vai ser monitorada, caso vc nao tenha um model com o mesmo nome vc pode usar o Mapper `new SqlTableDependency<Customer>(_con, "Customers", mapper: mapper));`.

essa linha `dep.OnChanged += Changed;` mais `void Changed(object sender, RecordChangedEventArgs<Customer> e)` se refere a watch na tabela escolhida, toda vez que tiver um `update`, `insert` ou `delete` vc vai ser notificado.

Link do github https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency

---

> Uma segunda opcao seria ServiceBrokerListener

Ativar o Broken no db: `ALTER DATABASE nomedodb SET ENABLE_BROKER`

usar o seguinte codigo no c#:

```
var listener = new SqlDependencyEx(connectionString, "nomedobancodedados", "nomedatabela");
listener.TableChanged += (o, e) => Console.WriteLine("Faz alguma coisa");
listener.Start();
//listener.Stop();
//desativar o listener
```

somente update:

```
var listener = new SqlDependencyEx(connectionString, "nomedobancodedados",
             "nomedatabela", listenerType: SqlDependencyEx.NotificationTypes.Update);
```

LInk do GitHub: https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener

Comment: A sim entendi, mas ai seria apenas para monitorar o que foi feito, usaria isso apenas para gerar log e tal, para salvar as alterações, usei trigger para salvar os logs.

Mas para o que quero não sei se é util.

Acho que é bem simples, normalmente o que vocês usam para atualizar um campo que é alterado por outra aplicação?

Comment: para esse tipo de aplicacao que precisa de uma resposta em tempo real, nao uso c# e sim node.js combinado com a interface do angular.

Comment: @GustavoPedro coloquei uma segunda opcao em c#

Comment: A sim, vou testar, quando a tabela sofrer alguma alteração eu executo algo?
Consigo especificar o nome da coluna da tabela?

Comment: nao mas vc pode validar depois que receber a alteracao

Comment: A sim, vou tentar isso e posto o resultado aqui, obrigado :D

Comment: Como vou especificar a Tabela que preciso? 
`using (dep = new SqlTableDependency<Customer>(connection, "Customers"));`
Você falou que isso é a minha tabela, mas onde coloco o nome?
Na string específico a conexão certo?

Comment: no lugar de Customer vc coloca o nome do seu model(caso seja igual a nome da tabela)